# QListView lazy load

Tags: qt, lazy-loading, qlistview

I have implemented a `QListView` with item model. And everything goes well until it has going not well when I have > 1000 data on it.

It slow in the first loading. After I check it on the model actually QListView load everything from the first time instead of load only the one that displayed.
I already set layout mode to batched and set the batch size to 100. But seems it does not work, it still load all data from the first.
Is there anything I can optimized it, something like lazy load (only load that visible on list view)?

**Update:**
The data was load from SQLITE and the Icon directly load from HDD. For the Icon, I have cached it once loaded.

Another question is : is it possible to make it load unload? My application now stand about 100Mb of RAM because need to load a lot of image that use on the QListView. And it possible to increase because the image is not complete yet today.

Comment: Where are you loading your data from?

Comment: Hello Demonplus, I have update the thread I made. It actually load from SQLITE and the Icon loaded from HDD directly but cached once loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can contribute here!

Perhaps what you need is `listView->setUniformItemSizes(true)`

(With this set to true, the QListView does not need to preload all items to plan the scroll bar size and position etc)